# fb_locale no longer supported when using og:locale:alternate?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebooks "og:" debugger

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

keeps giving me error:

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Object Missing a Required Value Object at URL '' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
```

On this line:

```
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES">
```

Reading here at stackoverflow I saw many articles that says facebook will add a  fb_locale and try to read the URL, like this:

http://foo.bar?fb_locale=es_ES

They also link to pages on facebook developer, but none of these pages exists
I can find nothing about this on facebook developer.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization

Does anyone have any information if `?fb_locale=es_ES` is still working?  Cause I cant seem to get any request with this querystring on my web server.

Any help, links or info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only environment in which that ever worked, were Open Graph stories. If your expectation is to get this to work for just regular link shares (so that it would display the preview content in the language of the user who views that post in their news feed), forget it - that was never implemented.

Comment: @CBroe   thats what I thought as well - We tried debugging the hell out of this and nothing seemed to work or be returned or anything.  And even the big sites failed on this point as well.   Thanks for confirming this